# How to cast FetchedResults<Obj> from @FetchRequest to [Obj]?

Tags: swift, core-data

How can I cast a `FetchedResults<Obj>` to an `[Obj]` in Swift?

```
@FetchRequest(
    sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Obj.name, ascending: false)]
) private var objects: FetchedResults<Obj>
```

I did the following:

```
objects as? [Obj] ?? []
```

But this is giving me the error:

```
Cast from 'FetchedResults<Obj>' to unrelated type '[Obj]' always fails
```

Comment: Glancing at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/fetchedresults it looks like you aren't going to be able to cast directly. Looks like you will need to manually take the results and convert them  Hopefully someone will come along and prove me wrong…

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As the error notes, you can't `as?` cast between unrelated types, and FetchedResults is not related to Array. If you need an Array, you can create it from any Sequence (such as FetchedResults), with Array's initializer:

```
let arrayObjects = Array(objects)
```

Comment: Did not know that it could be so easy :) thank you very much, this is working.